# Why are + and $\times$ considered continuous on a topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}$ is a topological vector space. Elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are real numbers. Every number on topological vector space is closed.

A function $f: X \to Y$ is considered continuous if every open set $\subset Y$ has an open pre-image in $X$.

But clearly given two real numbers a, b, $a+b$ and $a\times b$ produce another point. Points are closed therefore $+$ and $\times$ are not continuous operations.

Comment: All functions send points to points. You need to look at the inverse image of open sets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to define your topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I assume you're using the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ but this doesn't have to be the case. For example, if you're using the discrete topology, then all subsets are open (and closed) and every map is continuous.

Now, let $f_+: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$ and $f_{\times}: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $(a,b)\mapsto a\times b$. We want to show that for all open $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f_+^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $f_{\times}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. (Note: In the usual topology, this notion of continuity is the same as the analytical version. But let's proceed with the topological notions.)

Let's start with the map $f_+$. 
$$
f_+^{-1}(U) = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\vert a+b \in U\}
$$

We want to show that there exists an $\epsilon'>0$ (dependent on $(a,b)$) such that if $(a',b')\in B_{\epsilon'}(a,b)$, then $a'+b' \in U$. That is, $(a',b')\in f_+^{-1}(U)$, which says that $f_+^{-1}(U)$ is open.

$U$ is open, so let $\epsilon$ be such that $(a+b-\epsilon, a+b+\epsilon) \in U$. Then take $\epsilon' = \epsilon / 2$.

Then we have $a-\epsilon' < a'< a+\epsilon'$ and $b-\epsilon' < b'< b+\epsilon'$. Therefore, $a+b-2\epsilon' < a'+b'< a+b+2\epsilon'$ which is just $a+b-\epsilon < a'+b'< a+b+\epsilon$. Thus $f_+((a',b'))$ falls somewhere in the interval $(a+b-\epsilon, a+b+\epsilon)$, and is thus in $U$.

Now follow this same idea for the map $f_{\times}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to the definition. The requirement for continuity is on the preimage of the open set to be open. So knowing that (a,b) is closed and +(a,b)in R^2=a+b in R is closed says nothing about the continuity of the functions.